# Eclipse no longer useful

Tags: installation, java, android, eclipse

When I got my Eclipse from the Ubuntu Software Center, it was good and worked fine. I could work on Java projects fine.

This week I was required to add ADT and tried the ADT-bundle, assuming it had everthing I needed, seeing that the SDK had more steps. So now, I can create Android apps using the ADT-bundle.

I tried to work on my java projects again and I now discovered:

1. I can't run my java projects: "The selection cannot be launched. And
   there are no recent launches." error. I also believe Eclipse doesn't
   know it's a java program because it all in black and white. Not the
   usual green/blue/red/black things when making comments, variables
   and Strings.
2. I can't make new projects of ANYTHING unless I use the adt-bundle.
   New project only offers CVS (whatever that is)
3. My perspectives seem limited. I remembered more choices and now I'm
   limited to [Java], Resource, CVS Repository, debug, Team Sync. I was
   told to be able to use perspectives to swap between Android and Java
   developing. Even after the ADT installation using "Install new
   Software",nothing.
4. I can't uninstall/purge/remove Eclipse via the terminal. I tried
   removing it then reinstalling it via the Ubuntu Software Cetner. No
   results other than it's temporary removal.
5. (Possibly unrelated) A large number of repositories are not found
   when updating Eclipse. (See Step 8 in Summary of what I did...)

Although, on checking the versions and installation history, I confirmed Android and Java are installed. It probably just doesn't know it's there.

Eclipse Indigo: Version: 3.7.2 Build id: I20110613-1736

Summary of what I did before and during the problem:

1. Downloaded adt-bundle. Attempted instructions from teacher. (Install
   new Software) (Failed but other than an annoying "can't find
   repository" during each update, no damage to report) (Fixed)
2. Ran "eclipse" executable from the adt-bundle.
3. Updated Eclipse. (After restart, I noticed the problem)
4. NOTE: other than window arrangement, I had no customizations. Played
   around with the Windows>preferences and Project>propertied. Restored
   to default settings after no results.
5. Tried "apt-get purge eclipse". Couldn't find Eclipse so, nothing
   happened. Used Software center. No results.
6. Tried swapping workspaces. I tried different folder, deeper folder,
   renaming. All return the same problem.
7. Deleted adt-bundle (browsed folders then delete). Got Adt-sdk only.
   Installed. Can't find any changes other than some disk space usage.
   Of course, I can't make Android apps until I unzip the bundle again.
8. Windows>Preferences>Install/Update>Available Software Sites, Checked
   as many repositories as possible, then updated. Still nothing.

I'm about to get a second try on uninstalling it, because I think my last action will just be taking up space. But I'll wait for tomorrow, in case the answer will help. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is rather long to read... Could you shorten it at all?

Comment: That's a list... If I were to shorten it: "Eclipse can only make CVS. My old projects don't work and I can't make new projects"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to maintain separate Eclipses for ADT and regular Java.  The ADT does not play nice with others, as you've noticed.  The best thing to do is download the [ADT Bundle from Google](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).  This is pre-loaded and works well.

For all other Java, you can use the Eclipse in the Software Center but it is old and buggy.  I would download the latest version from the [Eclipse website](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).

Comment: Will try... I'll comment again to let you see how it goes... I had an old question that may be answered with what you posted as well. [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/312770/running-adt-bundle-in-eclipse-indigo)

Thank you.

Comment: It works... I read from someone one that when you have 2 kinds of Eclipse, one of them goes hay wire, tried it. Didn't happen... Although I have a new problem now regarding imports in Java...

Comment: Sometimes they can go a bit crazy.  I would recommend having different workspaces for each.  That can help some

Comment: As you have been noted, different version of Eclipse need different workspaces. I usually add eclipse version name into workspace name. I also try to use different workspaces for different types of development. Help me have some order in my projects. And I have not tried, but what version of Eclipse is demanded by ADT? Might be to old eclipse in the Ubuntu repository.